# Runtime Thread Access Violation Errors

Tags: multithreading, delphi-2010

[image: Violation Errors at Address 00732BB1]

My idea is to download all files from a folder and subfolders in a stringlist.

Next I use the `SHGetFileInfo` function to retrieve the names and type the date and links from the files to load into my Access database.

My application works fine, but when I use a large folder that contains hundreds of files, it blocks what I need to use the thread.

When I use the thread and my table is empty, it displays error messages, but the second time when my table contains records it shows no problem.

Procedure of searche

```
procedure FileSearche(const PathName: string; var lstFiles: TStringList);
const
  FileMask = '*.*';
var
  Rec: TSearchRec;
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(PathName);
  if FindFirst(Path + FileMask, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
    try
      repeat

        lstFiles.Add(Path + Rec.Name);
      until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(Rec);
    end;

  if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
    try
      repeat
        if ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and (Rec.Name <> '.') and
          (Rec.Name <> '..') then
          FileSearche(Path + Rec.Name, lstFiles);
      until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(Rec);
    end;
end;
```

Procedure of thread

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
{ debloc }

procedure debloc.execute;
var
  icn: HICON;
  SHFileInfo: TSHFileInfo;
  SearchRecord: TSearchRec;
  Size, I: Integer;
  lstFiles: TStringList;
  State: SHELLSTATE;
  lien, path: string;
  isEmpty : boolean;
begin
// to request windows to display the extension of all files

SHGetSetSettings(State, SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS, false);
  State.Data := State.Data or SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS;
  SHGetSetSettings(State, SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS, True);
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, nil, nil);

// for select folder 

  if SelectDirectory('Choisi un dossier ', ' ', path) then
    Lien := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(path) else exit;
    isEmpty := IsDirectoryEmpty(path) ;

// To verify that the folder is not empty
    if isEmpty = false then
    Begin
    if MessageDlg('Remarque Le dossier :'+#13+path +#13+'est vide il n y pas des fichiers à importer', mtInformation,
    [mbOK], 0, mbOK) = mrOk then
    exit;
    End;

// To verify that the folder is not folder systeme
  if
     (Lien = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SpecialFolder(CSIDL_WINDOWS)))
  or (Lien = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SpecialFolder(CSIDL_SYSTEM)))
  or (Lien = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SpecialFolder(CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES)))
  or (Lien = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SpecialFolder(CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86)))
  or (Lien = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SpecialFolder(CSIDL_MYPICTURES)))
  or (Lien = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SpecialFolder(CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES_COMMONX86)))
  or (Lien = 'C:\')
  then
  begin
//    ShowMessage(Lien+#13+'Erro, Les dossiers système sont ignoré pour votre sécurité');
    if MessageDlg(Lien+#13+'Attention, Pour des raison de sécurité les dossiers système sont ignoré ', mtWarning,
    [mbYes], 0, mbYes) = mrYes then
    exit;
  end
  else
begin
//To list the files in the StringList
  begin
    lstFiles := TStringList.Create;
    FileSearche(lien, lstFiles);
  end;

  if lstFiles.Count > 0 then
    for I := 0 to lstFiles.Count - 1 do

    begin
//To get the name, type, date, links of all files
        SHGetFileInfo(PChar(lstFiles[I]), 0, SHFileInfo, SizeOf(TSHFileInfo),
        SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or
        SHGFI_ICON);

      FindFirst(lstFiles[I], 0, SearchRecord);
      Size := SearchRecord.Size;

//To fill the Field of the table

      Form1.FDTable1.Edit;
      Form1.FDTable1.Insert;

      Form1.FDTable1.FieldByName('nom_file').ASSTRING := (SHFileInfo.szDisplayName);
      Form1.FDTable1.FieldByName('type_file').ASSTRING := (SHFileInfo.szTypeName);
      Form1.FDTable1.FieldByName('size_file').ASSTRING := (GetFileSizeAsString(Size));
      Form1.FDTable1.FieldByName('date_time_file').ASSTRING :=
        (DateTimeToStr(FileDateToDateTime(SearchRecord.Time)));
      Form1.FDTable1.FieldByName('lien_file').ASSTRING :=
        (ExtractFilePath(lstFiles[I]));

      Form1.ProgressBar1.Max := Form1.FDTable1.RecordCount;
      Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := Form1.FDTable1.RecordCount;
    end ;

  Form1.FDTable1.Post;
  Form1.FDTable1.First;

Form1.StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Nombre d"enregistrements: ' +
    IntToStr(Form1.FDTable1.RecordCount);

// to request windows to hide the extension of all files
  SHGetSetSettings(State, SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS, false);
  State.Data := State.Data and ($FFFFFFFF xor SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS);
  SHGetSetSettings(State, SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS, True);
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, nil, nil);
// procedure to rearrange the automatic columns 
 SetGridColumnWidths(Form1.dbgrid1);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
end;
```

to execute thread

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
BEGIN
 with debloc.Create do
  FreeOnTerminate:=true;
END;
```

When I use the thread and the table is empty, it displays the error message

> violation d'accès à l'adresse 00732BB1

But the second time, when my table is saved, it is not a problem.

Note: Despite this code that annoys me, the application works as even
another thing I do not know how to  stop the thread when the folder is very big. I close the application for the stop.

Comment: You can't access UI objects from a thread. Move all of that code out of your thread. Even when you fix that the code looks littered with mistakes.

Comment: as you see i c'ant use thread in this application

Comment: You cannot access `Form1` from a thread. You also can't access `Form1.StatusBar1` or it's panels, or anything else related to the user interface (no VCL controls at all). This is documented in the help, has been discussed at least dozens of times in previous thread questions, and is readily available with a simple Google search. It's also mentioned in the source code if you use `File->New->Other->Thread Object` in the IDE, in a large comment block at the top of the generated code. In case all of that doesn't make it clear, *don't touch any visual controls except in the main thread*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing the dbgrid component with the listview component

```
procedure debloc.transfertdata;
var
Myitem : TListItem;
MyColumn : TListColumn;
begin
  ListView1.Items.Clear;
  ListView1.Columns.Clear;

  MyColumn:= ListView1.Columns.Add;
  MyColumn.Caption:= 'Nom' ;
  MyColumn.Width := -1;

  MyColumn:= ListView1.Columns.Add;
  MyColumn.Caption:= 'Type' ;
  MyColumn.Width := -1;

  MyColumn:= ListView1.Columns.Add;
  MyColumn.Caption:= 'Taille' ;
  MyColumn.Width := -1;

  MyColumn:= ListView1.Columns.Add;
  MyColumn.Caption:= 'Date de modification' ;
  MyColumn.Width := -1;

  MyColumn:= ListView1.Columns.Add;
  MyColumn.Caption:= 'Lien' ;
  MyColumn.Width := -1;

  FDTable1.First;
  while not FDTable1.Eof  do
  begin
    ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    Myitem := ListView1.items.Add;
    Myitem.Caption:= FDTable1.FieldByName('nom_file').ASSTRING;
    Myitem.SubItems.Add(FDTable1.FieldByName('type_file').ASSTRING) ;
    Myitem.SubItems.Add(FDTable1.FieldByName('size_file').ASSTRING) ;
    Myitem.SubItems.Add(FDTable1.FieldByName('date_time_file').ASSTRING) ;
    Myitem.SubItems.Add(FDTable1.FieldByName('lien_file').ASSTRING) ;
    FDTable1.Next;
    ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;

end;
```

and in the thread I added

```
 Synchronize(transfertdata);
```